# PHP Mysql simplification

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help me simplify this?  I have a page for viewing a bunch of data from a table, the page is supposed to accept different values via GET calls.  I'd just like to slim it down a bit.  Again, the code works, it's just spaghetti to me.

```
if(!$_REQUEST['foo']){
    $bar = $_REQUEST['bar'];
    if($bar=='all'||!$bar){ $stmt = "SELECT * FROM table
        WHERE qty > 0  and
             somedate >= \"{$start}\"  and
             somedate <= \"{$end}\"
        ORDER BY id desc
        ";}
    else{
    $stmt = "SELECT * FROM table
        WHERE qty > 0  and
             somedate >= \"{$start}\"  and
             somedate <= \"{$end}\"  and
             bar = '$bar'
        ORDER BY id desc
        ";}
}
else{
     switch($_REQUEST['foo']){
       case 'all':
        $stmt = "SELECT * FROM table
          WHERE qty > 0  and
          somedate >= \"{$start}\"  and
          somedate <= \"{$end}\"
          ORDER BY id desc";
        break;
     case 'open':
      $stmt = "SELECT * FROM table
          WHERE qty > 0  and
          closd = 0 and
          somedate >= \"{$start}\"  and
          somedate <= \"{$end}\"
          ORDER BY id desc";
      break;
     case 'closed':
      $stmt = "SELECT * FROM table
          WHERE qty > 0  and
          closd = 1 and
          somedate >= \"{$start}\"  and
          somedate <= \"{$end}\"
          ORDER BY id desc";
      break;
}}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't for code reviews. You might have more luck at http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You can create Get Functions which returns the requested information. So 1 function for "bar" and 1 function for "foo"

Comment: could you identify what part is always the same in your query? hint: its nearly the complete statement but parts of the where clause - so it could be a good idea to set $stmt outside of your if/switch block and simply append the options you need afterwards. Also, I hope you santitize your inputs somwhere already.

Comment: Unless of course the code was originally badly designed, usually 'sliming down' is inversely proportional to making it more understandable. 

Since the code above is relatively short and doesn't seem to have any unusual constructs/design decisions I would suggest researching the parts you don't understand. Rewriting seems like wasted effort in this case.

Comment: It's a page to replace a whole mess of different pages that we had previously to view the same data.  It's only available internally, so I'm not really concerned about sanitation.  I'll look into codereview.  Newb me didnt realize it existed.  I'm also considering just loading all of the data and filtering it on the client side.  I've already got an input based filter on the page, so it wouldn't be very hard to do.  Thanks for all your input though guys!

Comment: I'd accept the comments from meager and najzero as being helpful for me as well.  I rewrote it with the conditionals outside of a generic $stmt.  I also know now to give this kind of thing to the guys over at codereview.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would handle the switch() assuming you have some sanity checks in the program.

```
<?php // RAY_temp_andy_foster.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$closd = '1=1';
switch($_REQUEST['foo'])
{
    case 'all':    $closd = '1=1';       break;
    case 'open':   $closd = 'closd = 0'; break;
    case 'closed': $closd = 'closd = 1'; break;
}
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE qty > 0 AND somedate >= \"{$start}\"  AND somedate <= \"{$end}\" AND $closd ORDER BY id desc";
```

var_dump($stmt);

HTH, ~Ray

Comment: Thank you.  I had to put some breaks in it, but besides that it removed a whole bunch of the mess from my page.  If you edit in breaks at the end of each case, I'll accept.

Comment: No, I just left it out as part of the simplification process.  But I did get the "closed" part wrong.  Cut/Paste error ;-)